# Java FX button highlight

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2

[image]

What I want to do is, Please see attached screen shot. Once I click on between buttons 1-4 it should be highlighted with red and 
stay as highlighted until I select any other button between button 1 and button 4 and then highlight the selected button should be 
highlighted. I can do this with focused property. But I have other buttons on my scene such that button 5,6 and 7. Once I click on any other button or click on another control
focus and red color goes away. But I want the clicked button stay as highlighted, or a sign that will show which button(between button 1 and button 4) is selected.

Comment: Did you look at [`ToggleButton`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ToggleButton.html)?

Comment: Yes, I tried togglebutton. But it did not work out. Once I click on any other buttons(button5,6,7) which I do not want to highlight it loses the focused property and not being highlighted anymore.

Comment: If by "highlight" you mean the focus indicator then you shouldn't set that by yourself because it confuses the user. The toggle button stays in its pressed state until another of its group is pressed. You will have to [edit] your question to provide context of what you're trying to do and what highlight you want.

Comment: Usually `RadioButton`s (and a `ToggleGroup`) are used for this kind of behaviour.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Basically, What I wan to do is, that I want to show which menu(button) is selected. I am thinking putting label next to the each button and when the button is clicked painting that particular button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using a `ToggleGroup` and `ToggleButton` for this. The `ToggleGroup` allows your user to only select one button at a time.  When the button is selected, you can then set the style you want.

In the sample program below, I've got 6 ToggleButtons in the group and only one may be selected at any given time. The selected button will have a red background (highlight).  Any buttons you create that do not have this styling will be unaffected.

The code below is commented as well:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Toggle;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ButtonHighlights extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Simple interface
        VBox root = new VBox(5);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        // Create a ToggleGroup to hold the list of ToggleButtons. This will allow us to allow the selection of only one
        // ToggleButton at a time
        ToggleGroup toggleGroup = new ToggleGroup();

        // Create our 6 ToggleButtons. For this sample, I will use a for loop to add them to the ToggleGroup. This is
        // not necessary for the main functionality to work, but is used here to save time and space
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            ToggleButton button = new ToggleButton("Button #" + i);

            // If you want different styling for the button when it's selected other than the default, you can either
            // use an external CSS stylesheet, or apply the style in a listener like this:
            button.selectedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {

                // If selected, color the background red
                if (newValue) {
                    button.setStyle(
                            "-fx-background-color: red;" + 
                            "-fx-text-fill: white");
                } else {
                    button.setStyle(null);
                }
            });

            // Add the button to our ToggleGroup
            toggleGroup.getToggles().add(button);
        }

        // Add all our buttons to the scene
        for (Toggle button :
                toggleGroup.getToggles()) {
            root.getChildren().add((ToggleButton) button);
        }

        // Show the Stage
        primaryStage.setWidth(300);
        primaryStage.setHeight(300);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

> **The Result:**

[image: screenshot]